# SSH to VM running on Virtual Box | kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: networking, server, ssh, virtualbox

Hi I'm running my VM on virtual box and trying to ssh to it from my MAC.

## Setup:

### Adapter 1:

- NAT
- Port Forwarding entry,
- TCP
- Protocol:  `TCP`
- Host IP:  `127.0.0.1`
- Host Port: `2222`
- Guest Port:`22`

### Adapter 2

- Attached to: Host-only Adapter
- Name: vboxnet0

After running: `ssh [server]@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 -vv`

I get the following error:

`kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`

terminal output: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UXWG0zoJrPgJUi0E33NvX7diPdUgfKbh5Rt1DZk4w8w/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There's a typo in your IP address. 127.0.01 is not a valid address.

Comment: Are you sure ssh server is running on vm? Check it by `systemctl status ssh`. You get a connection reset error which means target port turns out to be closed. If ssh is not running, try `sudo systemctl start ssh`

Comment: @user535733 thanks for the catch - I made a mistake while typing out the question but still have the same error

Comment: @MuhammedÖzen  I tried the command - and the ssh server is running on the vm

Comment: If you’re SSHing into a VirtualBox instance, the IP should be something unique. 127.0.0.1 would point to your host, not the VM, meaning a machine is SSHing into itself 

Comment: @matigo hmm, do you have any recommendations for how to get the correct VM address ?

I mostly followed these tutorials, which ran ```ssh [change]@127.0.0.1 -p 5679```: 
- https://medium.com/nycdev/how-to-ssh-from-a-host-to-a-guest-vm-on-your-local-machine-6cb4c91acc2e
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580525/virtualbox-port-forwarding-not-working-with-nat-adapter

Comment: Generally I’ve found VirtualBox instances easier to work with on a network if they’re using Host-Only and/or Bridged adapters. It will also be important to ensure that the network adapter’s “promiscuous mode” is set to “Allow All” 

Comment: can you give me your vm's local ip address that comes up when you type `ifconfig`?

Comment: @MuhammedÖzen https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zNMTwq7_hvO8xO1eXOq8ErJrOOUxNawRqQycRjk978k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If that's the only ip you get, you have no interface to talk to your host operating system. It's the loopback interface that basically send all the traffic back to your computer. You need to see something like eth0